# Sample Space in a binomial distribution

Tags: probability-theory

I am new to probability theory and statistics. But as far as I know in a binomial distribution it holds |$\Omega$| = 2$^n$, right? But what happens in case of n = 0?

Comment: There is one and only one outcome associated to $0$ trials, namely no fails and no successes (or, in your coin case, $0$ heads and $0$ tails).

Comment: …which means |$\Omega$| = 0, right? Is this even possible? Maybe |$\Omega$| = 2$^n$ for n not equal to 0, so that n = 0 would be just a case that is as undefined as the division thru zero?

Comment: No...if there is exactly one possible event, then the sample space has size $1$.  Granted, it's a pretty uninteresting sample space.

Comment: But there is no possible event, isn‘t it? For instance 0 heads and 0 tails in no trial means no event at all. I mean let H = Heads and T = Tails. How would your Omega look for n = 0, so $\Omega$ = {???}?

Comment: You keep asking the same thing.  The empty event is an event.  But that's more of a convention than anything meaningful.  It has the nice property that it means you can write $|\Omega_n|=2^n$ for all $n≥0$.  That can be convenient.  But it's hardly a deep and meaningful result.

Comment: So how do you write the „empty event“ in case of a coin toss (H,/T)? $\Omega$ = {$\emptyset$}?

Comment: Absolutely.  Why not?  But, honestly, I think you are perseverating on a convention.

Comment: One remark that might make you feel better about the convention:  it makes products work better.  Suppose you had a number of people with coins and say that some of them will toss their coin once, some will toss it ten times, and some will not toss it at all.  Under the convention that empty events are events the total probability space is the product of the individual ones.  Without the convention, you'd have to break out the non-tossing people.

Comment: @lulu: Do you think $\Omega$ = {$\emptyset$} in case of n = 0 of a binomial distribution is a convention/postulate or can one prove it from premises of probability theory? If the last, could u show how that‘d look formally?

Comment: Again, I think you are just perseverating on a convention.  Does it bother you that empty sums are $0$ and empty products are $1$?  But, if you prefer a different convention, go with that!  But, anyway, there is nothing special about a binomial distribution.  If nothing can happen, then the empty event is assured and has probability $1$.  Again, that works out very well when you have product spaces.  But, you should be able to rephrase the products in such a way as to exclude such cases.  Keep in mind that you have to deal with cases in which we don't know if the space is empty or not.